# Dynamic and recursive search for strings in windows Folder & subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, vbscript

I am trying to implement a recursive search script with following usecase:-

1. User can input string and directory to search for.
2. Script will list all the files with path that matches point 1 (maybe in separate file).

I tried it with batch script and tried to run from html page to pass parameters (string and directory). It failed [as mentioned over stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571366/how-to-run-a-batch-file-through-javascript) (due to javascripts inability to access file system.)

My batch script is :- `findstr /s /i /n  /C:@name= *.* v > results.txt`

Now I am wondering if my requirement can be fulfilled with batch file or I need to switch to vbscript. Please suggest.
I have no Idea of vbscript.

I can not install any third party tool on my windows workstation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is vbscript and won't trigger security dialogs if run from a local page.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
Searchterm = Inputbox("Enter search term")

ProcessFolder DirName

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)

    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Set Fls = fldr.files
    For Each thing in Fls
        Set contents = thing.OpenAsTextStream 
        If Instr(contents.readall, searchterm) then wscript.echo thing.path
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in fldrs
'        wscript.echo thing.name
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next

End Sub
```

**EDIT** and **EDIT2 (add browse for folder)**

In an HTA (I had to start from scratch - I couldn't make your butchering of my script work).

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD><TITLE>Simple Validation</TITLE> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Dim Dirname
Dim Searchterm
Dim FSO
Dim objOutFile

Sub Browse
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bffShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set bff = bffShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the My Documents folder", 9)
    If Err.number<>0 Then
        MsgBox "Error Setting up Browse for Folder"

    Else
        A = bff.ParentFolder.ParseName(bff.Title).Path
        If err.number=424 then err.clear
            tb2.value = A
    End If
End Sub

Sub Search
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("results.txt",True)
    Dirname = tb2.value
    Searchterm = tb1.value
    ProcessFolder DirName
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Set Fls = fldr.files
    For Each thing in Fls
        Set contents = thing.OpenAsTextStream
        If err.number = 0 then
            Test = Instr(contents.readall, searchterm) 
            If Isnull(test) = false then If Test > 0 then ObjOutFile.WriteLine thing.path
        Else
            err.clear
        End If
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in fldrs
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next

End Sub


</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><INPUT Name=tb1 TYPE=Text Value="Search">
<p><INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=Text Value="Folder"> <INPUT NAME="Browse" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Browse" OnClick=Browse>
<p><INPUT NAME="Search" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Search" OnClick=Search>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still struggling with running this vbscript from a local html form passing path and string variables........ Any hint???

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SanjeetSk/268b293682c14fa5ac7a

above is link to hta file..